# Badge layout is trying to escape

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, mobile-web

The badge layout on the mobile web site is broken. The gold tag is miles away from the bar and the bar is malformed.

> [image]

See the gold tag badge is place on the left top of the screen?

I am on a iPhone 6 on iOS 9.1.

Comment: Yeah, imprison this darn badge.

Comment: (And by the bar being malformed you probably mean it lacks the border-radius)

Comment: Yes. Text misaligned. Above the badges label there is the badge icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, as you may recall, we had some of our less files restructured - this is a victim of the restructuring.

I took a look and figured out there was a missing include and that some referenced files in the missing include needed to be pointed in the right place for the mobile view.

I've put the fixes in place and they will be with you in the next build.

Comment: Great work. I understand bugs like these fall through the cracks sometimes. Thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: Sorry it took this long.

Comment: No problem. You haven't seen my backlog yet ;)