# Mobile layout is really borked

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, mobile-web

The profile page page on the mobile web site is really broken now. Previously there were some minor issues, but now it is really broken.

> [image: Screenshot]

On iOS 9.2.1 Mobile Safari.

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: I want to give this a hundred up vote. Even the android app is terrible for such a famous network of professionals.

Comment: Maybe it's just me... but what exactly is broken? Might look ugly to some, but can't see anything missing or horribly broken in your screenshot. Also, what browser? Version? Device? OS?

Comment: Small sample http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269351/245360 @sha

Comment: What about it? That's a different bug report, still not solved. If this is a dupe, you better bump the existing report, but I guess you already know that, so I'm really confused by now.

Comment: @sha sorry for the confusion. The original report was just a small issue with the badge icon. This is a bug in the full layout.

Comment: @ShadowWizard There are padding issues in the badges section. Also, somehow a silver badge icon has made it all the way to the logo.

Comment: Well, "really broken" is big exaggeration but yeah, agree the design is bit off. The floating badge was already reported, @Yannis.

Comment: Reported months ago and ignored @ShadowWizard. Also, it's not just "trying to escape" anymore. It has escaped, and somehow found its way to the logo.

Comment: @Yannis 99% of the bugs are ignored by SE team, that is just how things work. (or don't work in this case)

Comment: The chunk of traffic that comes from mobile devices has been growing for quite some time now @ShadowWizard. SE may be ignoring a large number of bugs (and rightly so, in most cases), but at some point they got to realize that mobile users are as important to their traffic as desktop users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some .less files moved around yesterday, and got some quick fixes, which turns out broke some things like this on the mobile view.

We have fixed the direct issue here and are deploying as I write this.

Sorry about it - I know that the mobile view *was* looked at when things moved, but this page was missed.

Comment: Thanks. What about this one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269351/245360. Any idea when this will be fixed?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - I already pinged the designer who did the initial set of pages.